# Add class to div on another's click, remove class if body is clicked except for that div and child elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Working on a search module where the search icon is clicked, the form appears, and if you click anywhere on the body (except for the form) it slides away.

Currently have this, which applies the correct class on icon click, and removes on body click, but when you click anywhere on the form, it also hides. I'd like it to ignore the removeClass if the form is hidden (which is inside headerSearch).

```
$('html').click(function(e) { 
if(!$(e.target).hasClass('headerSearch') )
{
$('.headerSearch').removeClass('display');              
}
if($(e.target).closest('headerSearch').length)
return;
if($(e.target).hasClass('fa-search') )
{
$('.headerSearch').addClass('display');              
}
});
```

Comment: can you provide html also?

Comment: _Add a class to `X` when `Y` is clicked_ is an **extremely** common question on SO and the answer is pretty much the same for any X and Y.  Your X and Y are _div_ and _other div_ ... here is [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11068446/17300) where X and Y are _parent div_ and _div_.

Comment: What you'll want to do is stop event propagation when the `<form>` (or a div containing it) is clicked, so it doesn't bubble up to the `<body>` where the body click handler would act on the event and hide the form.  Check jquery's `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is stop event propagation when the  (or a div containing it) is clicked, so it doesn't bubble up to the  where the body click handler would act on the event and hide the form. Check jquery's [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

With only partial javascript, and no HTML in the question, it's difficult to be more specific.